# How do I select counts using two or more specific conditions in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

So I have a dataset of clinics in different zipcodes in a city from different time frames. How Do I count the number of clinics in each zipcode for the timeframe 2018-2019? So far, I can only count the number of clinics in total for each timeframe. I also want to add a new column or array for the result. Please see the code below:

```
df.groupby('Season')['Postal Code','Facility ID'].nunique()
```

This is the result:

[image: resultimage]

Also, can anyone tell me the equivalents of WHERE, GROUP BY and HAVING in SQL for Dataframes in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slice by `Season`, then group by `Postal Code`:

```
res = df.loc[df['Season'] == '2018-2019']\
        .groupby('Postal Code')['Facility ID'].nunique()
```

Your question on SQL equivalents is too broad: you may find the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) helpful.

Comment: thanks jpp but how can I create a new dataframe so that I can add the values generated to each column in a new dataframe for each season?

Comment: @cheena, Not sure exactly what you mean. I suggest you ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: thanks @jpp but how do i create a new dataframe and add this counts as data in new columns for each season. E.g a new sheet that shows all zipcodes and counts for 2018, then 2017, then 2016...and so on in a table

Comment: Try `df['count'] = df.groupby('Postal Code')['Facility ID'].transform('nunique')`, or [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).